# Attempting to place an ImageView between two text views?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I'm attempting to put two image views between 2 text views but my image either disappears or seems to be 'cropped out' when I run it on my Android device by one or both of the text views when I try and run it. Can someone let me know why this is happening?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.annagib.rileycard.Main"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="Riley Rayne"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rye"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/chomie" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="Poet. Writer. Innovator"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you have set height of all view as match parent which basically overlap your image view

Comment: use wrap_content in  both of the TextViews. and put adjustViewBounds and wrap_content in ImageView

Answer (score 0):

You should change all textViews and image views height and width to

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

> And The textview size is too big that is causing the problem. You should change its size to small.As well as atrribs

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

is responsible for the overlapping of views

Another way is to give weight to elements. And make height to `0dp`

ie.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="3"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.annagib.rileycard.Main"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Riley Rayne" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rye"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/chomie"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Poet. Writer. Innovator" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="cursive"
            android:text="Riley Rayne"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rye"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/chomie"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="cursive"
            android:text="Poet. Writer. Innovator"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```